# coordinate rotation, (x,y)=(y, (2x+3y) mod 5)

Tags: matrices, geometry, elementary-number-theory, combinations

While studying step mappings in KECCAK, I wonder why coordinate rotation is possible in the following algorithm.

```
base:

  (x,y)=(1,0)

for t from 1 to 24:

  (x,y)=(y, (2x+3y) mod 5)
```

[value of t, x, y]

```
0   1   0
1   0   2
2   2   1
3   1   2
4   2   3
5   3   3
6   3   0
7   0   1
8   1   3
9   3   1
10  1   4
11  4   4
12  4   0
13  0   3
14  3   4
15  4   3
16  3   2
17  2   2
18  2   0
19  0   4
20  4   2
21  2   4
22  4   1
23  1   1
24  1   0
```

thank you

Comment: The linear transformation
$$(x,y)\mapsto (y,2x+3y)$$ from $\Bbb{F}_5^2$ to itself is represented by the matrix
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&1\cr 2&3\cr}
$$
apparently has order $24$ in $GL_2(\Bbb{F}_5)$. Furthermore, its eigenvalues in the extension field $\Bbb{F}_{25}$ are primitive elements. Therefore iterating this transformation cyclically cycles thru the $24$ non-zero vectors of $\Bbb{F}_5^2$. This is what you are seeing.

Comment: Above I assume that by *coordinate rotation* you really mean that iterating the linear transformation amounts to cycling through the set of non-zero vectors.

Comment: The algebra of finite fields explains why to any prime number $p$ (in place of $5$) and to any number $n$ of variables (here $n=2$ as you have $x$ and $y$ only) there exists a linear transformation that similarly cycles through all the non-zero vectors $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ in $\Bbb{F}_p^n$.

Comment: @Jyrki It would help to give some citations since this is not always (explicitly) treated in common textbooks.

Comment: @BillDubuque Your suggestion is appreciated. I want to first make sure that I have correctly guessed what the question really was! A suitable umbrella context for this would be [linear feedback shift register sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register). In the general case where instead of bits the sequence entries take values in the field $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$. Alternatively, use the companion matrix of a primitive polynomial. However, it is possible that such explanations would not help the OP much. Future readers, yes. We'll see if the question survives.